# K&R C initialization without "=" finding option to support in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, initialization

I have some old K&R C code which has numerous initializations without the "=" assignment operator like so:

```
int ZCH NCH;
FILE *fout NULL, *errorf {stdout};
```

Without having to find and re-code all of these is there a gcc option that addresses this?

I tried std=c89 which was not sufficient.

Comment: Any chance its a typo in the source material?   I've been programming C for 30+ years, and never seen that.

Comment: It's absolutely everywhere all over the code.  It can't be a mistake!  I have download the UNIX V7 version of awk and lex and it is everywhere!

Comment: K&R 1 didn't have this

Comment: maybe you could try [pcc](http://pcc.ludd.ltu.se/), a port of the V7 compiler

Comment: I knew UTF-8 would screw us sooner or later `:)`. The `'='` signs are missing. Without them, there is no assignment or initialization (except in C++)

Comment: Example : https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/lex/once.c

Comment: @M.M Yeah I just tried my 1983 K&R C and it doesn't support this either.  Must be some AT&T standard lost to time!

Comment: I found one spot in V7 awk ([`proc.c`](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/awk/proc.c)) with initialization like that. An = was added there in the v7addenda tape, and since it's a separate program used to generate part of the awk source, might be a relic from an even older version. I wouldn't expect a modern C compiler to handle code from the 70's...

Comment: It looks like B used that syntax. Might be a holdover from it that existed during the very early development of C.

Comment: maybe the source code you are looking at is actually B ?

Comment: I think the easiest thing will be to change the code.  There are several dozen changes but in the end I know it will work!